# MapStore "Layer has not been loaded correctly"

Tags: geoserver

[image: "Layer has not been loaded correctly"]

Hi,
I have an issue to view the layer on another machine that is not local. In the local machine, i can view it perfectly fine. The layer was publish from the GeoServer and it was a GeoTiff file. It happen to shape file too. You could say any layer that is being added, could not load it.

On the first time I view it on other machine, there is no exclamation mark like in the picture, but the picture took so long to load. It happen the moment I refresh the page. I have tried to do it from scratch and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What URL is being used to fetch the layer? Have you set the proxy URL in GeoServer?

Comment: @IanTurton "http://localhost:8083/geoserver/wms" . No, i havent and I'm not sure how.

Comment: You need to use an actual machine name, localhost is always the machine you are on. Check the manual to learn how to set up GeoServer

Comment: @IanTurton i only use localhost on my local machine, but when i am using other machine, I'm using the local machine's IP address. Or I can't use the local machine's IP address to properly fetch/load the image.